# python-constraint - variable as random sample from domain

Tags: python, constraint-programming

I have been attempting to use the [python-constraint](https://labix.org/python-constraint) module to solve a problem whose output must be a list of lists containing random samples from a larger list, where each list must contain *at least one* element greater in value than any element in the preceding list.

So, if our input list is `[63, 70, 72, 79, 85, 90, 95, 96, 107, 121]` then a satisfactory output would be:

```
[[63, 79], [70, 72], [85, 90], [95, 107], [96, 121]]
```

The following would *not* satisfy, however, since all the elements in the last list are lower than all of those in the immediately preceding one:

```
[[63, 79], [70, 72], [90, 95], [107, 121], [85, 96]]
```

I imagined I might be able to use python-constraint to tackle this problem, but it seems that the module will only work on a flat list domain, where a variable corresponds to a unique element in the list:

```
from constraint import *

problem = Problem()
problem.addVariable("a", [1,2,3])
problem.addVariable("b", [4,5,6])

problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b: a*2 == b, ("a", "b"))
problem.getSolutions()
>>> [{'a': 3, 'b': 6}, {'a': 2, 'b': 4}]
```

So in the above "a" and "b" are bound to randomly-selected single elements from thier respective domains. What I need to do is pull out sub-lists from the larger collection, and then set up constraints on consecutive pairs of these sub-lists. It does not seem as if this is possible with python-constraint, however.

One solution I came up with is to pre-compute all possible pairs of values from the source list, then pass *that* as the domain:

```
from constraint import *
import itertools

source = [63, 70, 72, 79, 85, 90, 95, 96, 107, 121]
all_combs = list(itertools.combinations(source, 2))

problem = Problem()
problem.addVariables(["a", "b"], all_combs)
problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b: set(a).isdisjoint(b) and min(a)<max(b), ("a", "b"))
problem.getSolutions()
```

Although this seems crude it does work. The problem with it, however, is that I might want sub-lists with different lengths in a specific pattern, for instance a pattern of sizes 2,2,3,3, so that a solution would always have that form:

```
[[63, 79], [70, 72], [85, 90, 121], [95, 96, 107]]
```

Is there any (elegant/better) way to achieve that?

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on how your list is generated other than random? How important is it that it is fully randomized within the restriction you list (ie if you run this 1000 times do you want completely evenly distributed output, or is it ok if you end up with certain combinations being considerably more likely than others)?

Comment: @enderland Ideally it should be fully randomized, but at this stage I would not rule out possible solutions which are less than evenly-distributed.

Comment: `[[63, 79], [70, 72] ...` 79>72 Doesn't your first example violate the condition?

Comment: @xvan No, the condition is that _at least one_ element in the second list is higher than _at least one_ element in the first. I express this as `min(a)<max(b)`. `[[72, 85], [63, 70] ...` _would_ violate that condition.